# Text alignment in textbox in phpword

Tags: laravel, phpword

Currently I am struggling with the alignment in phpword textbox inside

I am not able to do perform align left, right and center.

```
$textbox = 
    $section->addTextBox(
        array(
           'alignment'    => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\SimpleType\Jc::CENTER,
            'width'       => 460,
            'height'      => 100,
            'borderSize'  => 1,
            'borderColor' => '000',

        )
    );

$textbox->addText("Form No. SH-1", array('align'=>'center'));
$textbox->addText('SHARE CERTIFICATE.', $fontStyle2);
$cell = $textbox->addTable()->addRow()->addCell();
$cell->addText('Pursuant to sub-section 3 of section 46 of the Companies Act, 2013 and rule 5-2 of the Companies Share Capital and Debenture Rules, 2014', $fontStyle2);
```

The above text I need to place in center if anybody knows let me know

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter of addText function is font styles and the third parameter is the paragraph styles to which the alignment rules belong to. So you just need to pass the alignment rules correctly as the third parameter:

```
$textbox->addText("Form No. SH-1", null, array('align'=>'center'));
```

Answer (score 0):

1. define a Paragraph Style to your new $phpWord class like this:

```php
$phpWord->addParagraphStyle('Paragraph', array('bold' => true , 'align' => 'center' ));
```

2. Add text to textbox like this:

```php
$textbox->addText('Hello World' , null, 'Paragraph' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the style for Alignment:

```
$section->addText('Hello Stackoverflow!', [], [ 'align' => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Alignment::ALIGN_CENTER ]);
```